# AJAX post with checkbox change in datatable columns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a datatable column with checkboxes containing `value=active` then its `checked` otherwise its `unchecked`.
Now I want to AJAX post to a PHP file with on `checkbox change event`, which will then update MySQL with value `active` or `inactive`.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sohal/gfuuazxL/6/) is what I have tried so far:

Comment: You can't use same `id` for several rows. Also I'd use an on-handler for the change-event as the table is dynamically populated.

Comment: @jtheman : thanks for the suggestion, any chance u can provide some example code?

Comment: @sohal07 see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `change()` before the checkboxes are created. Call it after your table has been populated.
You can use the `DataTable` `init` event to do it.

See my updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfuuazxL/11/).